# How to create a simple json result set?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to return a simple json result, something like:

```
{ 12323: true }
```

Or if I can't have a boolean value, then 1 or 0.

My spring controller is like:

```
@ReqeustMapping("/getResultFor")
@ResponseBody
public String getResultForXXXX(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    userId = 123;
    bool isSaved = true;

    // ????????? create object and convert to json
    //
    return someJson;
}
```

So I have my userId and bool variable, I need to wrap in in a structure and convert that to json.  I don't want to create a new class/type for this structure (preferrably).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been using Jackson for quite sometime. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson and been very pleased with it.  You would create a Java POJO with your fields and have Jackson serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Objects](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

```
 new JSONObject().put("12323", "true").toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just return a hashmap of this type from the method, with the return type of the method being `Map<Object, Object>`:

```
Map<Object, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
modelMap.put(Integer.valueOf(123123), Boolean.TRUE);
return modelMap;
```